# Given $P\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , $P$ is injective (one to one) polynomial function. Prove formally that $P$ is onto $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Given $P\colon\mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$ , $P$ is injective (one to one) polynomial function i need to formally prove that $P$ is onto $\mathbb{R}$

my strategy so far .......
polynomial function is continuous and since it one-to-one function it must be strictly monotonic and now i have no idea what to do ....

there is a theorem saying all continuous and monotonic functions have an inverse function and another theorem saying function have an inverse function if and only if its one-to-one and onto ...

but for formal proof of the on-to function property i think i need to show here that every element in the co-domain/target-set have a "source" in the domain .

i don't think its useful for this proof but only a polynomials of odd degrees have the one-to-one property .

Comment: Didn't you say there is a theorem that all continuous and monotonic functions have an inverse function -- and yours must be both since it is a 1-to-1 polynomial? Existence of the inverse implies it is defined on the entire domain, thus proving that your function maps to the entire codomain?

Comment: yes but there is little problem (or at-least i think its a problem) the theorem says every continuous and strictly monotonic functions have an inverse function from the image (image is not always the same as target-set .) so basically i get that function P is onto the image of P (every functions is onto her own image)

Comment: Can you use the intermediate value theorem? Because if you can, you just need to show your polynomial takes arbitrarily large positive and negative values; that would imply the polynomial takes on all values....

Comment: yes i can ... i even tried to do something like that, but failed to show that the polynomial takes any arbitrarily large/small values.I think there is something more i need to derive from the fact that its a polynomial because its not true for sigmoid functions so i assume its only true for polynomials .

Comment: Injectivity implies that the polynomial is of odd degree. Use the limits $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $x\rightarrow -\infty$, then Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: yes but how can i formally prove $\lim_{x \to \infty}P(x)=\infty$ or  $\lim_{x \to \infty}P(x)=-\infty$ ?

Comment: Do you know the formal definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} P(x) = \infty$? ("for all $N$ there exists $M$ such that...") Have you tried applying the definition to a polynomial of odd degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is in the right direction. A polynomial is continuous and given it is one-one it follows that it is strictly monotone. Now let $p(x)$ be that polynomial and let's assume that it is strictly increasing. Clearly we have the following:

1) $\lim_{x \to \infty}p(x) = L$ or $\infty$

2) $\lim_{x \to -\infty}p(x) = M$ or $-\infty$

But given the form of the polynomial the highest power of $x$ dominates other terms when $x \to \pm\infty$ and hence the finite limits $L, M$ are out of question. It follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty}p(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}p(x) = -\infty$ and by intermediate value theorem the range of $p(x)$ is whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, we show by induction that if $P$ has degree greater than or equal to 1, $|P(x)|$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $x$ arbitrarily large.

If $P$ is of degree 1, it is of the form $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x$ so for any $y_0$ we wish to obtain we can choose $x = -a_0/a_1$. If $P$ is of degree 2, it is of the form $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ which can be rewritten in the form $P(x) = p(x-h)^2 + k$ ($p,h,k\in\mathbb{R}$ always exist). Then, if $p$ is positive, any $y_0 > k$ can be found using $x = \sqrt{(y_0 - k)/p}+h$. A symmetric argument applies for negative $p$.

Now, if $P$ has degree more that 2, from Gauss we know that any real polynomial can be factored into quadratic and linear factors. Since each of these gets arbitrarily large (in magnitude) as $x$ gets big, it is trivial to show that their product also gets arbitrarily large.

Then, using froggie's comment, we can use the intermediate value theorem to get to the solution.

Comment: Showing that a polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ is unbounded (when $n\ge1$ and $a_n\ne0$) is much easier: by the triangle inequality, $|P(x)| \ge |a_n||x|^n - |a_{n-1}||x|^{n-1} - \cdots - |a_1||x| - |a_0|$, which is larger than $\frac12|a_n||x|^n$ when $|x| > 2(|a_{n-1}+\cdots+|a_1|+|a_0|)/|a_n|$.

Comment: Also, to use IVT to get surjectivity, you need more than $|P(x)|$ being unbounded: you need $P(x)$ unbounded above *and* unbounded below. (For example, your outline would also prove that $P(x) = x^2$ is surjective, which it's not.) That's why $P$ must have odd degree (which is implied by injectivity, as per i707107's comment).

Comment: thanks .... it looks solid .